# Messages from ValidationMessages.properties in generated JSON

Tags: valdr-bean-validation

I'm using the `ValidationRulesServlet` to generate valdr JSON for my APIs. Currently the generated JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "Person" : {
    "firstName" : {
      "size" : {
        "min" : 2,
        "message" : "{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}",
        "max" : 2147483647
      },
      "required" : {
        "message" : "{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}"
      }
    },
    "lastName" : {
      "size" : {
        "min" : 2,
        "message" : "{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}",
        "max" : 20
      },
      "required" : {
        "message" : "{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Jersey for my REST services and I want the `messages` in the above JSON to be replaced with values from `ValidationMessages.properties`.

My `ValidationMessages.properties` is located in classpath (`src/main/resources`) and is used correctly by Jackson. This can be confirmed by calling a REST endpoint with an invalid value. Here is an example response:

```
[
  {
    "message": "Must be between 2 and 2147483647 characters",
    "messageTemplate": "{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}",
    "path": "PersonServiceImpl.updatePerson.arg0.firstName",
    "invalidValue": ""
  }
]
```

The corresponding message in my `ValidationMessages.properties` is

```
javax.validation.constraints.Size.message = Must be between {min} and {max} characters
```

**How can I get the valdr JSON to output messages from `ValidationMessages.properties` rather than e.g. `{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, at least not out of the box. The reason is pretty obvious if you check the Bean Validation spec or look at the [`Constraint` Javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/1.1/api/javax/validation/Constraint.html):

> Each constraint annotation must host the following attributes:
>
> - String message() default [...]; which should default to an error message key made of the fully-qualified class name of the constraint
>     followed by `.message`. For example
>     `{com.acme.constraints.NotSafe.message}`

So, in essence `"message" : "{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}"` in the valdr constraint JSON signifies the message *key* rather than the actual validation `message`. It'd IMO be more sensible to call the JSON property `messageKey` to make this very clear but we wanted to stick with the Bean Validation lingo. In fact, all the properties in the JSON are extracted 1-by-1 from the Bean Validation `Constraint`.

So, you need a way to display "Must be between 2 and 2147483647 characters" in your AngularJS front-end if the `Person.firstName.size` constraint is violated. valdr achieves that by [integrating well with angular-translate](https://github.com/netceteragroup/valdr#integration-of-angular-translate).
All you need to do is to make your `ValidationMessages.properties` available to the front-end and to initialize angular-translate with the messages from that file.

Comment: I was afraid this was the case. I get your point, but still think it would make sense if Valdr used messages rather than keys whenever defined. With Jersey you can even use the `message` property of `Constraint` as the actual message, e.g. `@Size(min = 2, message = "At least 2 characters")`. I´d love if Valdr used this property in the same way.

Comment: It does. If you define `Constraint#message` in your Java class the message will end up in the valdr JSON instead of the (default) message key. There's no magic, nothing specific to Jersey or valdr, it's just how Java Bean Validation works. We do have a unit test for this at https://github.com/netceteragroup/valdr-bean-validation/blob/master/valdr-bean-validation/src/test/java/com/github/valdr/ConstraintParserTest.java#L86 if you'd like to see code.